# Hard to position on sub-elements in a drop down menu

Tags: css

Basically, what I have is a simple CSS drop down menu with background images for links. When I hover on an element that has a sub-element and then try to position on that sub-element, it's really hard and doesn't always work. Here's my snippet:

**css**

```
nav {
width: 710px;
}

nav ul ul {
display: none;
}

nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}

nav ul {
padding-top: 20px;
list-style: none;
position: relative;
display: inline-table;
}

nav ul li {
    float: left;
    width: 95px;
    height: 32px;
}
    nav ul li a {
        display: block;
        text-indent: -9999em;
    }

    .element, 
    .element:hover { width: 95px; height: 32px; }

    .home { background-image: url(img/home.png); }
    .home:hover { background-image: url(img/home1.png); }


nav ul ul {
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
}
    nav ul ul li {
        padding: 0;
        padding-right: 90px;
        position: relative;
    }
        nav ul ul li a {
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            color: #fff;
            font-size: 16px;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

            .sub-element, .sub-element:hover { width: 180px; height: 21px; }

            .interiorni { background-image: url(img/interiorni-vrati-active.png); }
            .interiorni:hover { background-image: url(img/interiorni-vrati.png); }
```

**HTML**

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" class="element home" alt="Начало"></a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" class="sub-element interiorni" alt="Интериорни Врати"></a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

What am I doing wrong? Any thoughts? Thank you.

Comment: post your html code please.

Comment: @Alek I added it. Sorry, I forgot about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For image replacement you can use another technique by Nicolas Gallagher who works well and used by Bootstrap http://nicolasgallagher.com/another-css-image-replacement-technique/.
Samuel thank's for jsfiddle.
Like he said, use child selectors `>`, because you have many parents rules, and rules repetition because of global selectors like `nav ul`.
Why you use `display:inline-table` if you use `float` on the `li` after, instead of something like `display:table-cell` or `display:inline-block`? Again every `li` gonna float and have 95px of width etc.

```
.element, 
.element:hover { width: 95px; height: 32px; }
```

Just before you declared that your link has `display:block` and his parent has same values. You need juste to leave height value, because block element take 100% of his parent's width : i've updated [JsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Fp9py/8/). Hope it's what you want

Answer (score 0):

I threw together a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fp9py/) for you - the problem you're having might be caused by a few issues. Your .element and .sub-element class is a bit clunky. Instead, try using [child selectors.](http://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/) It's hard to address without your HTML markup, though.

```
nav ul li a {
        display: block;
        text-indent: -9999em;
    }
```

This block in particular caused me issues when I tried to render - all the text was far offscreen. If you can, restructure your HTML and CSS.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I'll dig into child selectors more.